# To show all detail when orientation changes

Tags: swift

I am using iPad to run the app. for example, when iPad place horizontally, the width is 800px and height is 300px.

Now, The UItableview can show all details. However, when changing orientation, the width become 300px and the height is 800px. It can't show all the details.

The content is fixed size and fixed width in both orientation.  I don't want it to be dynamic.

> My question is how can I scroll the tableview horizontally to see all details?
>
> Is there any method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll the tableView horizontally in the following ways for solving the problem.

Firstly, take a look at this. This should solve your problem.

https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView
I did this and its works fine.

```
 CGRect frame = tblView.frame; tblView.transform =
 CGAffineTransformRotate(stressTblView.transform, M_PI / 2);
 tblView.frame = frame;
```

Another way is that you can use a UICollectionView, not a UITableView. Here you may implement cells and scroll in either direction.
In Interface Builder when you select the CollectionView it has a property called Scroll Direction. Change that to horizontal

Choose the one which best fit to you.